# UDP cannot receive when packets are split

Tags: c++, sockets

I am sending an array of uint32 over UDP to a device. To test the code, I also wrote a receiver that is listening and replies back what it receives. The tx is:

```
// From https://www.scaler.com/topics/udp-server-client-implementation-in-c/

// Client side implementation of UDP client-server model
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT     5005
#define RECEIVER_IP_ADDR "192.168.1.32"
#define MAXLINE 1024

// Driver code
int main() {
    int sockfd;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));

    // Filling server information
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(RECEIVER_IP_ADDR);

    int n;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(servaddr);

    // Create an array of uint32 to send
    uint32_t data_to_send[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    sendto(sockfd, data_to_send, sizeof(data_to_send), MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    printf("[TX] Message sent\n");

    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, &len);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("[TX] Received %d bytes\n", n);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

The Rx to test that works is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define PORT     5005
#define MAXLINE 1024

// Driver code
int main() {
    int sockfd;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    char *hello = "Hello from server";
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ( (sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));

    // Filling server information
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Bind the socket with the server address
    if ( bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,
            sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int len, n;

    len = sizeof(cliaddr); //len is value/result

    n = recvfrom(sockfd, (char *)buffer, MAXLINE,
                MSG_WAITALL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr,
                &len);
    // buffer[n] = '\0';
    printf("[RX] Received %d bytes: %s\n", n, buffer);
    sendto(sockfd, (const char *)buffer, n, MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, len);
    printf("Hello message sent.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

With that Rx, I see that the same number of bytes I send are received. However, when I change to the device, I can see the packets coming in wireshak in three packets (as expected). One on a different port used to send (5007) and then two packets on the same port I used to send (5005). Here is the screenshot from wireshakr:
[image]

Even though the packet lengths differ, the data is correct, as expected (there are extra things added by that is not the problem).

Can it be the problem that there is first something sent over 5007 and recvfrom hangs waiting on 5005? Can it be that there is a difference in the packet lengths between sent and received?

Thanks for the help.